# Slide and Rotate a slider with content from the right

Tags: jquery

I want to implement the red rotating slider using Jquery like the one used for side-menu on http://javascriptissexy.com/

Any ideas on how I can achieve it? Any help will be great.

Comment: Here is a link to what I have tried. Thanks!.http://jsfiddle.net/rtarranum/078ydf0c/..

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code you've tried. Remember that people are helping you for free, so it's in your best interest to make it easier for them to do so rather than asking them to jump through hoops by sending them to external sites.

Comment: You are very close, actually, just add transition, where it needs to be: http://jsfiddle.net/078ydf0c/1/

Comment: @nevermind Thank you !!